# От какого источника будет питаться usb при подключении usb и пинов 5v и gnd

Tags: arduino

Если одновременно ардуино подключено и по usb и к питанию через пины 5в и gnd, то какое питание будет приоритетней и откудо ардуино будет брать энергию на подачу 5в на свои пины?

Comment: От обеих источников в разных пропорциях. Тот кто будет отдавать под нагрузкой напряжение выше - в его пользу будет перекос. Если большая разница потенциалов - то напряжение может пойти и обратно к источнику с меньшим напряжением от источника с большим (и например сжечь цепи питания USB порта). Ардуино вроде 3-х вольтовые, или путаю?

Comment: @nick_n_a Зависит от чипа на плате и от частоты, 328p(мини\нано\....) - может питаться от 3в с частотой до 8мгц, и с частотой до 16мгц при 5в =)
Есть чипы которые вообще не дружат с 5в, для них предел 3.3в =) (http://arduino.ru/Hardware/ArduinoDue)

Comment: @nick_n_a рабочее напряжение плат arduino 5 В. Максимальное напряжение 20В, но значение выше 12В, быстро выведет плату из строя.